# ReferenceError: document is not defined error Typescript in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

The idea is I m trying to get all HTML headers (h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6)and test if they are in SEO-friendly order. If I try to run it I get this ReferenceError: document is not defined error Typescript in Playwright error

```js
async assertHeadingsOrder2() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/require-await
  await test.step('Test html header structure for catalog page', async () => {
    // Get all the heading tags (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) in the document
    const headingTags = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');

    // Define a function to test the hierarchy
    function testHeadingHierarchy() {
      const hierarchy = [];

      headingTags.forEach(heading => {
        const tagName = heading.tagName.toLowerCase(); // Get the tag name (e.g., "h1", "h2")
        const level = parseInt(tagName.charAt(1), 10); // Extract the numeric level from the tag name

        // Check if the hierarchy is valid
        if (level > hierarchy.length + 1) {
          console.error(`Invalid hierarchy: ${tagName} is not in the correct order.`);
        }

        // Update the hierarchy array with the current level
        hierarchy[level - 1] = tagName;
      });

      console.log('Heading hierarchy is valid:', hierarchy.join(' > '));
    }

    // Call the function to test the hierarchy
    testHeadingHierarchy();
  });
}
```

Comment: I definitely will add an assertion at the end, but since the code wasn't working, I was trying to get logs and see what I got.
Seo-friendly means that It is important to use headings to show the document structure. <h1> headings should be used for main headings, followed by <h2> headings, then the less important <h3> , and so on. So basically, this order is SEO friendly h1 --> h2-->h3--> h4 and so on. 
For a wrong order example---> h1--> h3 or h2-->h4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playwright doesn't automatically make `document` available to you in Node. Instead, it gives you `browser` and `page` objects with an extensive API to manipulate the website through.

You could use `page.evaluate()` to run code in the browser and access `document`, but usually, you'll select elements with the [locators API](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators) on the `page` object.

Your CSS selector should be `"h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"` rather than `"h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6"`. The former uses commas for "or" logic, while the latter selects an `<h6>` nested inside of all other headers.

Here's an example:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const failMsg = (prev, curr) =>
  `h${curr} was more than one level deeper than previous header h${prev}`;

test("detects a skipped heading", async ({page}) => {
  test.fail(); // expect this test to fail
  const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h4>4</h4>
  </body></html>`;
  await page.setContent(html); // replace with page.goto("<Your URL>"); when you're working with a real site
  const headers = await page
    .locator("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
    .evaluateAll(els => els.map(el => +el.tagName.slice(1)));

  for (let i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
    expect(
      headers[i] - headers[i-1],
      failMsg(headers[i-1], headers[i])
    ).toBeLessThan(2);
  }
});

test("handles a valid structure", async ({page}) => {
  const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h3>3</h3>
  <h4>4</h4>
  <h4>4</h4>
  <h2>2</h2> <!-- it's OK to skip back, just not forward -->
  <h3>3</h3>
  </body></html>`;
  await page.setContent(html);
  const headers = await page
    .locator("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
    .evaluateAll(els => els.map(el => +el.tagName.slice(1)));

  for (let i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
    expect(
      headers[i] - headers[i-1],
      failMsg(headers[i-1], headers[i])
    ).toBeLessThan(2);
  }
});

test("handles a valid structure on a real site", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions");
  const headers = await page
    .locator("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
    .evaluateAll(els => els.map(el => +el.tagName.slice(1)));

  for (let i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
    expect(
      headers[i] - headers[i-1],
      failMsg(headers[i-1], headers[i])
    ).toBeLessThan(2);
  }
});
```

For your actual tests, you'll probably use `page.goto()` rather than `page.setContent`, which is used here purely to help demonstrate the assertion logic easily.

You may want to use a [custom matcher](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#add-custom-matchers-to-your-expect) to help abstract the verbose error template message and the explicit loop and/or write a helper function to extract headers.

Also, this assertion doesn't auto-wait, but I assume headers are probably OK to grab more or less in one-shot. If that assumption isn't true, try [`poll`](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expectpoll) or [`toPass`](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expecttopass).

Comment: It worked; thank you. Do you know how to implement for random page? because as HTML body, we are giving specific orders to test it. What if we want to run this code for random page and test its HTML header correct or not?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, use `page.goto(yourURL)` rather than `page.setContent`, which is only injecting a specific page for the purposes of providing simple examples to test the logic with, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "random" page--you mean literally selected at random, or a page not known in advance?

Comment: I meant in this code, is it gonna work for all pages? Also, the reason behind the question is that I want to make sure if the wrong header was added to other pages or not(here, imagine you have a catalog page, setting page, and so on on the shopping page.). With that code, we just added a specific HTML body.
`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
      <h1>1</h1>
      <h2>2</h2>
      <h3>3</h3>
      <h4>4</h4>
      <h4>4</h4>
      <h2>2</h2> <!-- it's OK to skip back, just not forward -->
      <h3>3</h3>
      </body></html>`

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. That's a hardcoded example test case to help show the behavior of the algorithm. Other pages will have different HTML that will replace it. For example, try replacing that with `await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions")` and see if the test passes. I've added an example.

Comment: I see your last example is working for random pages. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to get all errors on the page instead of getting first error and stopping? Maybe like this?

`console.log(headers)
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus, id-length
    for (let i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
      expect(headers[i] - headers[i - 1], failMsg(headers[i - 1], headers[i])).toBeLessThan(2)
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        // If there are errors, throw them all at once
        throw new Error(`Multiple header hierarchy issues:\n${errors.join('\n')}`)
      }
      errors.push(errors)
    }`

Comment: I'd probably write a custom matcher, since it'll add some verbosity and may make the error message less clear. The array is the right idea, but don't use `throw` or `try`/`catch`. Instead, move the `expect` to the end of the loop and assert once using a sensible error message based on the errors you found in the loop. Maybe ask a new question, since we're getting a bit out of scope of the original issues (not using `document`, the hierarchy validation algorithm, etc). Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) if it's resolved your original concerns.

Comment: I asked it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444607/how-to-get-all-errors-and-assert-them-or-add-them-into-report-on-the-page-inst)